# Solr: ClassicFilterFactory with acronyms & use of Solr's analyzer

Tags: search, solr, lucene, tokenize

I have a schema.xml with a text type, that uses tokenizers, filters... at index and other at query time. Now I have the problem, that a search query, which should return some results, doesn't return anything. So I thought, using Solr's analyzer would bring me closer to the root of the problem.

I have the following string: `Foo Bar Ges.m.b.H`

This is my schema.xml definition for the field type text:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ClassicFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" catenateWords="1" catenateAll="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="30"/>
    <filter class="solr.ReverseStringFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="30"/>
    <filter class="solr.ReverseStringFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ClassicFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" catenateWords="2" catenateAll="1" preserveOriginal="1" splitOnNumerics="0"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

When I search for `Foo Bar` I get all the results back, so the problem lies within the `Ges.m.b.H.` (notice the missing dot at the end). I have a few questions about this:

**1. ClassicFilterFactory**

`ClassicFilterFactory` only works on acronyms that are in this format `LETTER.LETTER.LETTER.`. For example, `G.m.b.H. -> GmbH`. But it doesn't work on acronyms like `G.m.b.H` (missing dot at the end) or `Ges.m.b.H.` or `Ges.m.b.H` . Is there a way to get this to work? For now, I'm doing it with the `WordDelimiterFilterFactory`, but it would be good to know, if there is a better way.

**2. Solr's Analzer**

I tried to analyze the index and query time with solr's analyzer. My text get's splitted on index and query time, as expected. When I fill out the field for index and query, I get this highlighted fields that look like, if there was a *hit*. Here are some screenshots:

[image: Index time, LowerCaseFilterFactory]

The screenshot above is from index time of `Foo Bar Ges.m.b.H`, `LowerCaseFilterFactory`. I also get "hits" at other filters like my last filter `ReverseStringFilterFactory`:

[image: Index time, ReverseStringFilterFactory]

The next screenshot is from query time:

[image: Query Time]

To me, it looks like, Solr is looking at the last line of my query tokenizer/filter stuff, and searches for hits in the indexed documents, and if there were some hits, they get highlighted. But unfortunately, **this search doesn't return any hits,** when used in my normal search.

I drilled it down to exclude any other queries:

`http://localhost:8982/solr/atalanda_development/select?q=foo+bar+ges.m.b.h&defType=edismax&qf=vendor_name_search_text`

## Summing up:

1. Any ideas, why this doesn't work?
2. Am I right, that the highlighted, kinda purple fields, are hits? Can someone explain, HOW Solr is doing this, so that I can understand this in the future?
3. Any suggestions to the `ClassicFilterFactory` problem would be great!